# UK visa refusal on opening balance and also company affidavit of support letter

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, visit

I hope someone on this forum will be able to answer my question regarding my visitor visa application.

I am from Pakistan. I applied for s standard visitor visa on 11/3/2024 in Islamabad. On 27/03/2024 I received a refusal, the ECO saying that he was satisfied about the opening balance, brought forward in my bank account, although I provided six months of bank statements in which I received my monthly salary credited each month regularly.

But the ECO told me that he was not satisfied about the origin of the funds despite the fact that I provided an employment contract, a leave letter and salary slips for six months.

The second objection was on the affidavit of the support letter from the employer that I provided. The ECO was not satisfied, saying that he didn't know how they would support me. Ignoring the company support letter, so in this regard I am waiting for a positive response.

He refused my application for a visit visa because he is not satisfied that I meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 and V4.6 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:

• You have applied to visit the UK for 11 days for tourism.

• You state that you are employed as an Admin manager and earn 235,000.00 PKR (£667.28) per month. You have provided a letter from your employer to confirm your employment and some payslips.

• You state that the cost of your visit is £1000, and your employer will give you £1000 towards the cost of your visit. You have provided letter purportedly from your employer dated 11/03/2. However, the information provided does not demonstrate their current financial circumstances is such that they can afford to give you £1000. You have provided your personal bank statement account ending 9262. Whilst I note the documents provided appear to demonstrate that you hold the funds required to cover the costs of your trip. However, I note an opening balance of 1,290,373.00 PKR (£3,664.01) on 07/10/23, the information provided does not demonstrate the origins of the this fund. I am therefore not satisfied that you have accurately portrayed your current personal financial circumstances in your country of residence. This in turn leads me to doubt your intentions and credibility in wanting to visit the UK on this occasion. This has undermined the credibility of your application and leads me to doubt you true intentions to the UK.

• The onus is on you, the applicant, to show that you meet the requirements of the immigration rules based on your overall personal circumstances and that you will comply with all the conditions associated with any visa to come to my decision, I have considered, not only those documents stated above, but all the documents you have provided regarding your circumstances. I am not satisfied that you meet all the requirements of the above paragraphs of the Immigration Rules for visitors.

• In assessing your entry clearance application, I have considered all of the documents and information provided against the requirements of Appendix V and have also taken into account the published Visit guidance. The guidance indicates a number of factors which can help assess if an applicant is a genuine visitor, including but not limited to the following:

• Their financial circumstances as well as their family, social and economic background.

• Their personal and economic ties to their country of residence.

• The concerns noted in the paragraphs above mean that I am not satisfied that you have accurately declared your personal circumstances, which in turn means I am not satisfied on the balance of probabilities that you are a genuine visitor.

While I note the information you have provided regarding your travel plan, employment letter, however I am not satisfied that these other factors outweigh the concerns noted above. Therefore, I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor and that you will leave the UK at the end of your visit. Your application is therefore refused under paragraph V4.2 (a), (c) of the Immigration Rules.

• Rate of exchange:352.17 PKR :  £1 (reference – [www.oanda.com](http://www.oanda.com) at the date of this

Comment: How big is your employer? How many employees? Are you traveling for business? If not why is your employer giving you a month and a half salary?

Comment: My employer give me the support for my outstanding performance but ECO objected on my opening balance which seems somehow weird

Comment: @Aman note that if they give you money for you trip and that trip is not related to business, in most countries, and I suppose in Pakistan as well, that's considered wages (or benefit in kind if they pay directly instead of giving you the money), and it must be reported and taxed accordingly.

Comment: The ECO say they are not convinced that your employer can give you the £1000, in that case it's sane (and actually to your advantage) that they also consider your personal finances, It's in doing that he questions your initial balance.

Comment: You might have avoided the refusal if your enployer had actually paid you the £1000 *before* you applied for the visa and you could prove the source of the funds via your payslip, and demonstrate that the money is available to you. But how are you planning to spend 11 days in the UK sightseeing on £1000? The cost of a return flight from Pakistan alone could be say 40% of that figure, a cheap hotel would be say £25-30 a night. Have you visited the UK before?